# java generic inheritance. overloading or overriding

Tags: java, generics, overloading, overriding, type-erasure

please compare two code snippets:

**snippet1:**

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Child<String> p =new Child<String>();
        p.m("1");
    }
}
class Parent <T>{
    void m(T t){

    }
} 
class Child<T extends CharSequence> extends Parent<String>{
    void m(T t){

    }
}
```

result([online compiler](http://ideone.com/CoqWma)):

> Main.java:13: error: reference to m is ambiguous, both method m(T#1)
>   in Parent and method m(T#2) in Child match        p.m("1");        ^   where
>   T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
>       T#1 extends Object declared in class Parent
>       T#2 extends CharSequence declared in class Child

**snippet2(only one change!!!):**

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Parent<String> p =new Child<String>();
        p.m("1");
    }
}
class Parent <T>{
    void m(T t){

    }
} 
class Child<T extends CharSequence> extends Parent<String>{
    void m(T t){

    }
}
```

this code compiles good!([online compiler](http://ideone.com/CoqWma))

**please clarify this diference.**

Comment: Just wondering: will this work: `class Child<T extends CharSequence> extends Parent<T>{` ?

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux it is really work))) generics crashe my brain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are in fact not overriding the `m(T)` method of `Parent`. So, you have two separate functions available:

- `Parent.m(String s)`, because you forced the T in Parent to be String
- `Child.m(T)`

Imagine this declaration for Child:

```
class Child<T extends CharSequence> extends Parent<Integer>
```

Now, the `Parent<T>` gets to be `Parent<Integer>`, which means that the `m` method of `Parent`, now is a `m(Integer i)` method, while you have in your child class still a `m(T)` method available. Now the difference is clear.

You chose `T` to be a `String`, which coincidentally extends `CharSequence`, but that doesn't make it override the `m(T)` method of Parent. So, changing your signature to:

```
class Child<T extends CharSequence> extends Parent<T>
```

should work. Now you are really overriding the method of Parent in Child.

Comment: Is it compile time resolution?

Comment: Yes, it is a compile time problem. The compile can't choose between those two methods.

Answer (score 3):

So the thing is here that what you have going on actually *isn't* overriding. Notice that if you add the `@Override` annotation to `m()` in `Child` you'll get a compilation error in both cases:

```
Main.java:22: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
```

---

You can imagine `Child` actually looking like this:

```
class Child<T extends CharSequence> extends Parent<String>{
    void m(T t){

    }

    void m(String t) { // <-- This was the method inherited from Parent

    }
}
```

So when you try

```
Child<String> p =new Child<String>();
```

The compiler sees the reference type `Child<String>` and sees that you actually have *two* methods that could work, as you have the `m(String t)` that was inherited from `Parent<String>` and `m(T t)` defined in `Child`, where `T == String`. Because now you effectively have two `m(String t)` methods, you'll have an ambiguous call.

Now, if you have

```
Parent<String> p =new Child<String>();
```

The compiler sees the reference type `Parent<String>` and uses that to resolve the call to `m(String)`. As `Parent<String>` only has one such method defined, there is no ambiguous method call, so the code compiles.

This is one of the reasons why the `@Override` annotation should *always* be used -- there's no confusion about whether you are overloading a method or overriding it.

---

Interesting fact: If memory serves this is actually one of the few times where generics are *not* erased. If you decompile `Child` you'll see the header

```
class Child<T extends java.lang.CharSequence> extends Parent<java.lang.String>
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is overloading(not overriding)? I prepare to exam and I cannot use IDE when I pass it.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Because you have two methods with the same name that have different arguments. You inherit `m(String t)` from `Parent<String>`, and you declare `m(T t)` in `Child<T extends CharSequence>`. In order to override you need to have the overriding method's signature be a subsignature of the original method's signature. The precise rules are defined in the JLS section 8.4.8.1, but usually "same signature" is a decent approximation.

Comment: Thus override or overload - it is resolves in compile time. This rules same for String Integer MyCustomClass and T. My change - it is runtime hack.

Comment: @gstackoverflow I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say here... But as this is overloading, it's bound at compile-time, which is why you get a compile-time error. I'm not quite sure what you mean by runtime hack... Because the compiler uses the *reference* type of a variable to determine what methods are available to bind.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Child` class gets around the rules of overriding (and goes into the realm of overloading) by declaring a method with a parameter that depends on a bounded type. That type may be `String` or it may not be, so there is no clash with the method declared in the parent class when compiling the two.

However, when compiling your `Ideone` class, by declaring the type argument as `String` in

```
Child<String> p = new Child<String>();
```

the type `String` is bound to the type parameter `T` which `Child` declares and uses in `Child#m(..)`. Therefore the method appears as

```
void m(String t) {}
```

But so does `Parent#m(..)` because of the type argument `String` in the `Child` class declaration.

```
class Child<T extends CharSequence> extends Parent<String> {
```

As such, the `Child` class has two `m(String)` methods for that invocation. The call is ambiguous.

In

```
Parent<String> p =new Child<String>();
p.m("1");
```

the `Child` class method is not visible since your reference is of type `Parent`. There is no ambiguity.